# Get data highchart from php table

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, highcharts

i want to show every row data from my table to highchart, how can i show that data using php to javascript foreach row?

```
<script>
    series: [{
          name: 'Mie Instan',
          data: [<?php foreach ($query as $row){echo $row['mie'];}]
     }, {
          name: 'Beras',
          data: [<?php foreach ($query as $row){echo $row['beras'];}]
     }, {
          name: 'Telur',
          data: [<?php foreach ($query as $row){echo $row['telur'];}]
     }]
</script>
```

Comment: just build the complete data first in PHP, then in the end, `echo json_encode()` when the structure is complete

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I would do, in order to get the [HighCharts data arranged as an array of numerical values](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series%3Carea%3E.data), is to use php [array_push](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php) and [PHP foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) to sort the data in three different PHP arrays.

```
<?php
// Declare 3 new arrays.
$mie=[];
$beras=[];
$telur=[];

// Fill the arrays with the database values
foreach ($query as $row){
    array_push($mie, $row['mie']);
    array_push($beras, $row['beras']);
    array_push($telur, $row['telur']);
}
?>
```

Then use the arrays to produce a string of "coma separated values" in the HighCharts script, using [PHP join](http://php.net/manual/en/function.join.php), like this:

```
<script>
    series: [{
          name: 'Mie Instan',
          data: [<?php echo join(",", $mie); ?>]
     }, {
          name: 'Beras',
          data: [<?php echo join(",", $beras); ?>]
     }, {
          name: 'Telur',
          data: [<?php echo join(",", $telur); ?>]
     }]
</script>
```

Hoping this helps...
;)